# JqueryMobile/CSS HTML5 app - alter graphic once pressed

Tags: jquery, android, html, jquery-mobile

I'm struggling trying to add an 'on press' event to a button within a HTML5 Android app, I would like the button to switch background images once pressed (so that it appears altered in the brief seconds between the page changing).  I've seen this done in several apps but cant get it to work via on click or on press methods on mobile.

Can anyone recommend a good method to achieve this effect?

Comment: would it be possible to use the pagebeforechange method? or has it to happen explicitely when clicking a button?

Comment: Hi Zyrex- not sure, but i'll give it a go - thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the .ui-btn-active CSS class? That's what JQM uses to mark a button as active/pushed...